# Automate MATLAB and LTspice

Tags: bash, scripts, matlab, automation

I'm using MATLAB and LTspice. I have to write a script to automate these two softwares in such a way, 
 1. Output file of the MATLAB is feed into LTspice.
 2. LTspice output results are inserted back into MATLAB file.

How to script these automation ?

Answer (score 1):

Do I see this right that LTspice is a windows program that only runs under wine and doesn't have any command line interface? I don't know much about neither MATLAB nor LTspice, but I seriously doubt that there's any way to script an application under these circumstances. I'd be happy to be corrected if I'm mistaken though!

### Edit

The best I can come up with is a key press automation, I use `xdotool` for this, examples being

```
xdotool key --window 11 alt+r # sends ALT+R to window with id 11
xdotool type 'random text' # types "random text" in current window
xdotool mousemove 50 50 click 1 mousemove restore # moves mouse to 50 50, performs a left click and returns cursor to previous position
```

For more information read [xdotool's manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xdotool.1.html) – “You can also write scripts that only execute xdotool”!

Comment: Yes! LTspice runs under wine. I do open MATLAB [/usr/local/MATLAB/bin/matlab start] and LTspice [env WINEPREFIX="/home/hmv/.wine" wine C:\\Program\ Files\\LTC\\LTspiceXVII\\XVIIx64.exe] by giving their executable path in command line (I use bash script). 
After opening softwares, I do not know how to type and run files on each windows [MATLAB & LTspice] and interface between. 
Thank you for your suggestion, I will check with xdotool once.

Comment: I'm not able to display the MATLAB documentation without logging in, but it has [some pages about command line options](https://de.mathworks.com/help/search.html?qdoc=command+line&submitsearch=) – maybe they'll help? There's reason for hope that you'll be able to automate at least the MATLAB part of the job.

Comment: I don't know it, but `wmctrl` seems to be an alternative to `xdotool`.